# Android soap web services pass paramaters with type of object

Tags: android, web-services, soap, mapping, ksoap2

Web Service: 
`<soap:Body>
    <GetQueryStringLoginWithParameters xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <user>string</user>
      <password>string</password>
      <logonuser>string</logonuser>
      <parameters>
        <TopBarVisible>boolean</TopBarVisible>
        <LeftMenuVisible>boolean</LeftMenuVisible>
        <Action>string</Action>
        <ProcessFilter>string</ProcessFilter>
        <Parameters>string</Parameters>
        <DisableEBA3>boolean</DisableEBA3>
        <Mobile>boolean</Mobile>
        <DelegationFrom>string</DelegationFrom>
        <DelegationFromType>int</DelegationFromType>
        <Delegated>boolean</Delegated>
        <DelegationId>int</DelegationId>
        <SourceSystem>string</SourceSystem>
        <TestMode>boolean</TestMode>
        <ActivePosition>string</ActivePosition>
      </parameters>
    </GetQueryStringLoginWithParameters>
  </soap:Body>'`

I want to add parameters like "TopBarVisible","LeftBarVisible","Action". But I didnt. Android Code :

`SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

```
            QueryStringLoginParameters parameters = new QueryStringLoginParameters();
            parameters.setAction(action);
            parameters.setMobile(true);

            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("parameters");
            pi.setValue(parameters);
            pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
            pi.setType(parameters.getClass());
            request.addProperty(pi);
            request.addProperty("user", username);
            request.addProperty("password", password);
            request.addProperty("logonuser", logonuser);
            try {
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,"parameters",new QueryStringLoginParameters().getClass());

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE (URL);
            androidHttpTransportSE.debug = true;

            androidHttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String url = response.toString();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();`
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

`

I get error as "Invalid action paramaters System.String[]"